# How to establish 3 UART and 2 I2C interface at a same time in STM32F103C8T6?

Tags: stm32, freertos, stm32cubemx

I am a newbie to STM32 and CubeMX. I need to create 3 UART interface and 2 I2C interface in STM32F103C8T6. I tried to, but there is a common port for both i2c and uart communication and it allows me to create only (2 uart and 2 i2c) or (3 uart and 1 i2c ) and I couldn't create as I needed . how can I establish 3 UART and 2 I2C interface at a same time in STM32F103C8T6 ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the reason for using two I2C interfaces? I2C is a bus. So a single bus can connect many devices.

Comment: @Codo as log as they both are I2C masters and there is no address conflict.

Comment: And if you don't have to use both buses at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There's an unresolvable pin conflict.

The I2C2 peripheral must use pins PB10 and PB11 for SDA and SCL -- there are no remappings for this peripheral.

The USART3 peripheral uses those pins for TX and RX. On higher pin-count STM32F1 parts, it can be remapped to pins PC10/PC11 or PD8/PD9; however, the STM32F103C8 doesn't have those pins.

There are only two I2C and three USART peripherals on the STM32F103, so there are no alternate I2C or USART peripherals available.

Comment: Maybe you could use the 2 uart / 2 i2c solution and create the missing UART via software.
As said by duskwuff, a pure hardware solution is not possible.

Comment: @theSealion implementing an I2C master in software would be simpler, as there are only minimum delay requirements.

Comment: @berendi I would say that depends on his requirements. So maybe you are right or may I'm :-)

Answer (score 1):

use hardware I2C and as many as possible hardware UARTS. For the additional ones write the software implementation. You have an example here: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00110292.pdf or take stm32F103 with more pins